# How to execute PostgreSQL 'get diagnostics'

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

The PostgreSQL 9.3 manual describes this command

```
'GET DIAGNOSTICS int_var = ROW_COUNT;'
```

to get the count of affected rows from last `insert/update` command. 
When I try this in the GUI (pgAdmin 3, SQL editor pane) and in Python (using psycopg2 package) I get this error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "GET".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's backend functionality, not a part of SQL language.
Psycopg2 has cursor.rowcount attribute containing this value.
Libpq C/C++ library has PQcmdTuples function.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the best...cursor.rowcount works great.

Answer (score 17):

[GET DIAGNOSTICS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html) can be used only inside a plpgsql function. You cannot execute it as a regular sql command. See the following simple example:

```
create table fruits as
select * from (values
    (1, 'banana'),
    (2, 'pear'),
    (3, 'apple')) f(id, fruit);

create function update_fruits()
returns setof fruits language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    n int;
begin
    update fruits set id = id+ 1;
    get diagnostics n = row_count;
    return query select null::int, format ('%s rows updated', n);
    return query select * from fruits order by 1;
    get diagnostics n = row_count;
    return query select null::int, format ('%s rows retrieved', n);
end $$;

select * from update_fruits()

 id |      fruit
----+------------------
    | 3 rows updated
  2 | banana
  3 | pear
  4 | apple
    | 3 rows retrieved
(5 rows)
```